On the equivalence of ARIMA models with ETS
It is often said that exponential smoothing models can, in some cases, be seen as ARIMA models. For instance, if we have a simple exponential smoothing model:
$$X_t = l_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$$
$$l_t = l_{t-1} + \alpha \varepsilon_t$$
as given in https://otexts.com/fpp2/ets.html, then this should be somewhat equivalent to an $\operatorname{ARIMA}(0,1,1)$-model.
I do not see this equivalence, I am aware of ressources like https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-ets.html where this statement is given, but there is no real explaination. How does one see this equivalence, and what exactly does equivalent mean here? I tried looking at $X_t - X_{t-1}$, this gives:
$$X_t - X_{t-1} = l_{t-1} - l_{t-2} + \varepsilon_t -\varepsilon_{t-1}$$
which does not seem to be a $\operatorname{ARMA}(0,1)$ process.

So, given your edit, have you found a satisfactory answer to your question? If so, please do go ahead and post it as an answer. We are explicitly encouraged to self-answer, which furthers the aim of SE to build a repository of high-quality answers.

That said, here is a not-unimportant detail: it's not that "exponential smoothing models can, in some cases, be seen as ARIMA models", because exponential smoothing is not a model. It is a forecasting method that only acquired a model as a foundation multiple decades later in a state space framework. A more correct claim would be that "exponential smoothing is an optimal forecasting model for certain ARIMA data generating processes".

Hyndman et al.'s textbook on Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing: the State Space Approach would be a very good starting point.

@StephanKolassa I am aware of that source. I diagree with the fact that "exponential smoothing is not a model". It is a model, its the one I gave above. But I agree with your description that it started as an algorithm, and only later became embedded in the model form I gave above, which then translates to a state space model. That beeing said, it is always important to correctly specify what is meant when talking about exponential smoothing, the model or the algorithm.

Apparently one comes up with solutions once one asks on stack exchange:
If we rewrite $$l_{t-2}=l_{t-1} - \alpha \varepsilon_{t-1}$$ and plug this into the above equation, we get:
$$X_t - X_{t-1} = \varepsilon_t + (\alpha -1)\varepsilon_{t-1}$$
which indeed is an $\operatorname{ARMA}(0,1)$-process.
